# Insert byte array in the place of blob using hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, blob

The code in my controller

```
FileInsertion fileInsertion = new FileInsertion();
FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
fileUpload.setFilename((InputStream) new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray));
    //byteArray is the file converted into a byte[]
fileInsertion.insertFile(fileUpload);

    //the following happens in a separate method
trns = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(fileUpload);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

The hibernate mapping file

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.sort.process.FileUpload" table="fileupload">
        <meta attribute="class-description">
            This class contains the file upload detail. 
        </meta>
        <id name="Id" type="int" column="Id">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>

        <property name="filename">
            <column name="filename" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My aim is to insert a file into a db table in the place of BLOB object.
However I am getting this

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.io.InputStream, at table: fileupload, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(filename)]
```

I tried the above using `ByteArrayInputStream` instead of `InputStream` , but in vain.
Can anyone please let me know what is my mistake in the code?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use byte[] directly in your model, should work. ie, `fileUpload.setFilename(byteArray)`.

Remember that it is better to use meaningful names. Someone might expect that `fileUpload.getFileName()` return the file name, not the raw data.

Comment: Excellent, thank you it worked just fine. Also I followed the tip of naming the method `setFile(...)` and `getFile()`